# Rails Nested Form - Items Dynamically Added All Get Zero Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am having trouble with my nested form.  I am using Ryan Bates' code.  Gemfile snippet:

gem "nested_form", :git => 'https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'

The problem is that when I try to use *link_to_add* I get a new item which looks normal, but it doesn't work because it gets a new index of 0 instead of a 'random' index based on the current time that the nested_form.js is supposed to generate.  Every item that I add gets the same 0 index. So of the effect is I cannot add a new item (or only the last new one is saved, depending on the original state of the model).

The behavior is the same with a new parent object and when editing a parent object.

I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong since I was able to do a simple new app that works.  But I can't figure out what is wrong with my real app.

The nested_form.js generated for my (working) test app and my (not working) real app are identical.  So I don't think there is a problem with a version difference.

I used Firebug to step through the code in nested_form.js but was not able to figure out why it was generating a 0 index there.

My parent model has this:

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :levels, :allow_destroy => true
has_many :levels, :dependent => :destroy, :order => :depth
```

My form is instantiated like this:

```
<%= nested_form_for(@course) do |f| %>
```

The part with the nested object is like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :levels do |builder| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= builder.text_field :name %></td>
        <td><%= image_tag(builder.object.icon) unless (builder.object.icon.nil?) %></td>
        <td><%= builder.link_to_remove "Remove" %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
   <tr><td><%= f.link_to_add "Add a level", :levels %></td></tr>
```

I don't see any difference between my code and my working example (or other examples I've seen).

Does anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE:

After trying to debug this some more in Firebug I realized the 'blueprint' used by the addFields function in nested_form.js was being changed inside the addFields method and that's why it wasn't putting in the generated index (that block was being bypassed in my test app).  So I overrode the block where this happens by changing:

```
if (context) {
```

to:

```
if (false)
```

This seems to fix my symptom from preliminary testing but I sense that in some contexts (NPI) this may have broken something else (maybe with multiple levels of nesting?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I feel somewhat silly I think this is something that might happen to someone else (and I did say in my question I was probably doing something 'wrong').

What I was doing 'wrong' was I was using fieldsets to segregate areas of my form.  And I was giving the fieldsets the class 'fields'.  Not good.  Conflicts with classes of the form generator.

Comment: Haha, that sounds about right. But in all honesty last time I tried to use the `nested_form` gem, I felt like it was doing trying to do WAY too much in effort to be everything for everyone. Since then it looks even more complex. I ended up just rolling my own solution with the help of his code it took me about a full day of work and understanding but I came out able to do just about anything I wanted with my solution. For more help check out [this blog post](http://blog.madebydna.com/all/code/2010/10/07/dynamic-nested-froms-with-the-nested-form-gem.html)

Comment: Yea I saw that post.  It's a pretty complicated subject so I'm actually impressed that it works as well as it does.

Comment: @KenThompson, If I dont specify "fields" class for nested fields, link_to_remove does not work, it does not hide nested fields.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation when my parent object did not have any fields of its own:

```
Carousel has_many Items
<%= f.inputs 'Carousel' do %>
<!-- NOTICE NO FIELDS HERE -->

  <f.fields_for :items, allow_destroy: true do |it| %>
    <%= it.input :media_hash %>
    <%= it.link_to_remove 'Remove item' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add 'Add item', :items %>
<% end %>
```

By adding a field on my parent object, the indexes were being created correctly.  In my case I simply added `f.input :created_at, as: :hidden` to my Carousel.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue (on updates, not create), except the only instances of "fields" classes in my html are generated by the fields_for helper, so am very frustrated.

Have spent almost a full day stepping through the javascript, but see no reason why it should replace "new_" strings with invalid "0" indexes.

My hack that fixed it was adding a check in the content-editing loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < parentNames.length; i++) {
          if (parentIds[i] && parentIds[i] !== "0") {
            content = content.replace(
              new RegExp('(_' + parentNames[i] + ')_.+?_', 'g'),
              '$1_' + parentIds[i] + '_');
           ...
```